# ExpressionEngine - some channels not outputting content

Tags: expressionengine, mediatemple

So I've created a fair few EE sites before but never come across this issue, recently installed EE on a mediatemple grid host and all seemed to be working fine until I created multiple channels, some of the channels are refusing to output any content at all where as others will output content fine, using the most basic of code so there's definetly no issues in the actual template code.

Any ideas as to how I could go about fixing or debugging this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Have you tried adding an if no_results? Did it work? Some template code would be helpful. Although we can't give a proper opinion without more details, I find in situations like this, turning off the dynamic parameter fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on template debugging and the output profiler in `Admin > System Administration > Output and Debugging`. Reading through those logs should give you a very clear idea of what's stopping your channels from rendering content.

Answer (score 0):

it would definitely be helpful to see example code - both working and non working. I would also double check to see if you need to use dynamic="no" in your channel entries tag. One other thing confirm that the channels that are not working actually do have content in them and that the field names have no typos in your template code.